# win32api & pyhook - How to get the user's typing language?

Tags: python, winapi, multilingual, keyboard-events, pyhook

I installed [pyHook](http://pyhook.wiki.sourceforge.net) and successfully attached handlers to keyboard events, but now I need to find out whether the user is typing in English layout or other layouts. I couldn't find this information in the event objects.

How do I find on windows what the typing language in the focused window is? I tried playing with *GetKeyboardLayout* with no success (it always return the same value whether I type in English or in a different language - in my case Hebrew).

Thanks

Solved thanks to BrendanMcK's reference.

Python code:

```
from ctypes import windll, c_ulong, byref, sizeof, Structure
user32 = windll.user32

class RECT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("left", c_ulong),
        ("top", c_ulong),
        ("right", c_ulong),
        ("bottom", c_ulong)];

class GUITHREADINFO(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
    ("cbSize", c_ulong),
    ("flags", c_ulong),
    ("hwndActive", c_ulong),
    ("hwndFocus", c_ulong),
    ("hwndCapture", c_ulong),
    ("hwndMenuOwner", c_ulong),
    ("hwndMoveSize", c_ulong),
    ("hwndCaret", c_ulong),
    ("rcCaret", RECT)
    ]

def get_layout():
    guiThreadInfo = GUITHREADINFO(cbSize=sizeof(GUITHREADINFO))
    user32.GetGUIThreadInfo(0, byref(guiThreadInfo))
    dwThread = user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(guiThreadInfo.hwndCaret, 0)
    return user32.GetKeyboardLayout(dwThread)
```

Comment: Don't post answers in your questions. Submit an answer instead. That allows others to vote on it, and you to accept it. The result is a better user experience, making it easier for future visitors to find good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12383335/660175) to a similar question; seems you need to use GetGUIThreadInfo to determine the current active thread on the desktop, and then pass that to GetKeyboardLayout.