# get current windows keyboard layout in Java

Tags: java, windows, locale, keyboard-layout

On windows I want to get the code I see in language bar on windows. I need to get this current keyboard layout at any given time.

If I use this in a thread:

```
InputContext is = InputContext.getInstance();
System.out.println(is.getLocale());
```

I'll get layout that was active when the program was started. But when i press either win+spacebar or alt+shift and change layout to something else, the thread will keep outputting previous language.

I didn't find any parameter that would reflex on keyboard layout in system properties either.

Thread example:

```
    Thread t = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                InputContext is = InputContext.getInstance();
                System.out.println(is.getLocale());

                Properties p = System.getProperties();
                System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.language"));
                try {
                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(InputContextTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    t.run();
```

Comment: Why do you need this? On X11 implementations (e.g. Linux), keyboard layout can change at any time!

Comment: See the [MappingNotify](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/window-state-change/mapping.html) X11 event

Comment: But I do not care about X11. I need it on windows. I want to get the code I see in language bar on windows. That's all.

Comment: Then you should edit your question to tell that

Comment: That should be no problem with JNI or probably it is stored in the Windows register (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java)

Comment: This won't make a difference in your case, but it should be t.start(), not t.run(), otherwise there is no point in using a thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you will have to write some JNI to get it. There are 2 functions of interest in Windows API :

- `GetKeyboardLayout` : will give a DWORD whose lower word identifies language and sublanguage -> to use if you just switch between a limited an known list of layouts
- `GetKeyboardLayoutName` : will (almost) directly give you a null terminated string - extract from documentation :

  Syntax

  ```
  BOOL GetKeyboardLayoutName(LPTSTR pwszKLID);
  ```

  Parameters

`pwszKLID`
[out] Pointer to the buffer (of at least `KL_NAMELENGTH` characters in length) that receives the name of the input locale identifier, including the terminating null character ...

Comment: this helped me along with the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379713/cant-get-current-keyboard-layout thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) for this:

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef

val layout: WinDef.HKL = User32.INSTANCE.GetKeyboardLayout(0)
```

Gradle:

```
 implementation("net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:5.12.1")
```